# TypeScript - function argument types equality

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a problem with using a generic in a class. There's a class `Item` that accepts a generic `T` that extends constraining `ItemValue` type and there's a type `Items` that contains instances of `Item` typed as `Item<ItemValue`>.

The problem is that the compiler does not pass a potentially valid generic argument through `ItemValue` constraint because `callback` property of `Item` is using it as a callback value.

If I removed the `callback` property from the class, there would be no error.

Further, I tried to replicate this without class, and there's no such error. Do you think it's a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsBqBDANgV2gXigOwwQCMIAnKAHygGdhSBLPAcwG4AoN0SKAYXTSIoAxgGsAPABUAfFFwAKAG7osALigSAlLJkKA9vQAm7NkLQpq1WPASSoEAB7w8By3ESpMEGQG82UKGAMSvBQSp5qEsb%20APTRsABmUCC6GFBCuggIEHjAUMAAFvSWKcAANHn5ZNAA7vRoaFAk%20Lp2pKS6pH4BQSghQvyComp89YPi0rJQclrYPlAAvhz%206Xi0pBhCwB2KyhARWr7%20-gVFAHRhWJMXEOz%20i4uc4NBuCJa4h1AA2owGDmprjCYAF01C8xC8PFgpGx5sY0BBcvRrNRQcjJh9-Cg1HgINUrIgxADmFI5AByUlaWKtdqdRZUiRPKCksFEphSUlQIrNXLmaj0Jh4FBEeF5FpcaDM6zg6yQryk05sKnqJ7FRKBXSQUigJn9UbCEQclCkaCMdIIMC9ejCiAKpXK7ikkYCfWEuiA9mcyx4XQ8iz8wXW0V5RmOgYuiG7dm2uJHfwMh0Rzwcrne318gVCkVbYMO1nyxUx2NxkMEYhkZNen1QXn%20zPQbPipl5hUcemFSy1erVtDUFrG6gYNCIvDVmj0BB1I3UjoFnPQACCeBekzBiah7Cp8J5akXy9wOLxLLdxLJFOMs4AElU8qQQICgwYxZUaCgslBagUSqPTLyFfEMHgmz0LoI4oAYBhOmMtgOE4Lj4sgkZyEIRDDGGoiSFIBwcIs-6AcAwEjvEui6EhKG8Gh4isphUAYlAVIAHItOq1qvO%20SL5AEGDAPhzDkXq6FUUGkHhjKkZdDEcQwJYSKjkQGBMAA-OJ1bgcJoikRo7DzEAA)

```
type ItemValue = number | string;

type Callback<T> = (value: T) => void;

class Item<T extends ItemValue> {
  private value: T;

  // If you comment this out, there will be no error
  private callback: Callback<T> = () => { }

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

type Items = {
  [index: string]: Item<ItemValue>
};

let items: Items = {
    a: new Item<string>('') // error
}
// Type 'Item<string>' is not assignable to type 'Item<ItemValue>'.
//  Types of property 'callback' are incompatible.
//   Type 'Callback<string>' is not assignable to type 'Callback<ItemValue>'.
//      Type 'ItemValue' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.


// This will also result in a similar error
// type AnItem = Item<ItemValue>;
// let a: AnItem = new Item<string>('');

// Here trying to do the same without a class.
function addCallback<T extends ItemValue>(cb: Callback<T>) {

}
function prepareAddCallback(cb: Callback<string>) {
    // No problems with putting Callback<string> to Callback<ItemValue>
    // Is it a bug?
    addCallback(cb);
}
```

### Update:

As @Joey pointed out in his answer:

> `string` is assignable to `string | number`, but `(val: string) => void` is not assignable to `(val: string | number) => void`

```
type CallbackStrOrNum = (value: string | number) => void;
const addCallback = (cb: CallbackStrOrNum) => { };
addCallback((value: string) => { }); // error

let x: string | number = ''; // ok
```

This narrows down the issue. My question now would be, why is that?

### Update 2

To be clear, I solved the issue in this example by defining `private callback: Callback<ItemValue> = () => { }` instead of `private callback: Callback<T> = () => { }` Having the generic in the callback parameter was not critical here. The lesson here is to not define function types properties that have a generic, as then the class will be inextensible, e.g. `Item<number>` would not be assignable to `Item<string | number>`
Also, in the real example, it was a dictionary of callbacks, in case you are wondering why I didn't define `callback` as a regular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `string` is assignable to `string | number`, but `(val: string) => void` is not assignable to `(val: string | number) => void`.

In your example, `Item<string>` is not actually assignable to `Item<string | number>` because the `callback` properties don't have compatible types (i.e. `(value: string) => void` is not assignable to `(value: string | number) => void`).

Edit:

To be clear, this is by design and is a natural consequence of the type union operator (`|`). Otherwise, the following code would compile, which would certainly be an issue.

```js
const callback: (value: string | number) => void = (str: string) => {str.toLowerCase()};

callback(4);
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot! I updated my question. It seems a little weird that it works differently with the callbacks.  Do you know why is that?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide an example of why this behavior is necessary.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to point to the documentation for [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) which explains why function arguments need to be checked *contravariantly* for type safety (instead of the usual *covariant* checking you need for, say, function return types, or the unsafe-but-sometimes-useful *bivariant* checking that the compiler used to do for function arguments before this was introduced).

Answer (score 0):

I changed this and it removed the error:

```
let items: Items = {
    a: new Item<ItemValue>('') // (No) error
}
```

I believe it's because ItemValue can be a string OR a number so Item< string> wouldn't specific enough. It would also work with:

```
let items: Items = {
    a: new Item<string | number>('') // (No) error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for engaging the question, but this isn't it at all.  `string` should pass as `string | number` and it does - if you remove `callbacks` property or in my last example with `addCallback`. (I didn't downvote you).